# Making key repeat behavior consistent across Windows and UNIX operating systems

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, terminal, input, typing

I split my time between Linux, macOS, and Windows about evenly. This is because there is software that is unique on all 3 systems that I need to use regularly between work and leisure.

Lately I have seen a lot of success in bringing a shared work environment within the terminal (I use tmux and vim heavily in a terminal interface) onto all of these environments. I of course started down this path originally with Linux but the transition of these tools to macOS was very easy, and windows has been a far harder nut to crack. Previously I used tools like Git Bash and MSYS shell, but now an even better solution exists via WSL2. Windows Terminal Preview, I discovered recently, is very capable and fast, so I am planning to spend more time in Windows now.

Anyway, so much of the software runs perfectly well now that the only differences which remain are idiosyncracies between the operating systems that actually go down very deep.

One of these is the behavior of key repeating.

In macOS, in a typical application, key repeating isn't really a thing. If you hold letter keys it will pop a menu after a little pause to let you choose accented letters and things like that. However, in terminal applications like alacritty and iTerm, key repeat works, and this is important for me because I use vim and keys like h, j, k, and l to move around in text and scroll.

In Linux the behavior is simpler, it's similar to windows.

However there is a difference between windows and Linux/macOS, and it is this: If you hold down a key to start repeating the key, on Windows if you press shift at this point, it will stop the repeating. On macOS and Linux, the key will become shifted and continue to repeat.

I actually prefer the latter behavior, but I actually expect this to be unusual because I can't actually think of typical use cases where this is desired, *except* for the way I have been using my binds, where I actually bind `H` to move left by 7 characters (`h` moves left by one character by the default binding) in vim. That is to say, I came up with my own non-standard key binds that turn out to sort of exploit this keyboard behavior in macOS and Linux, where tapping shift while holding down movement keys allows for a kind of very responsive "turbo" mode while navigating around.

Unfortunately for me, this muscle memory has taken hold a bit and it's causing some friction when I edit code in the terminal from windows!

Originally I was going to look into configuring the terminal to adjust this, but I'm not so sure that it's the right abstraction layer to do this at, considering that the behavior does appear to be consistent system-wide.

So I am asking if any Windows experts out there know of any OS tweaks that can change the keyboard handling behavior to the one that I'm used to? If I hold down a key <kbd>A</kbd>, and it starts typing for me "aaaaaaaaaaaa", at this point when I push down <kbd>Shift</kbd>, I'd like for it to *immediately* begin to emit "AAAAAAA".

Comment: Is this just within WSL2 terminal?, do you see the same behaviour in notepad?

Comment: Yeah, it's like this in all text areas under the windows 10 operating system. I think the default behavior is like this and has been since the beginning of time...

Comment: Please see this gaming SE Q/A - https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/344489/cant-long-press-alt-or-ctrl-only-once-at-a-time - the solution provided I may also resolve your issue

Comment: @CraftyB Thanks, that's interesting. Well, the settings that are provided by the GUI are not useful at all to me, but there's a possibility that manually editing flags in regedit might get me somewhere. You may be onto something but I don't really have a map to navigate those settings with yet.